# PTV Vissim: How to increase the ParkDur(0) duration for the Parking Lot

Tags: ptv-vissim

How to increase the ParkDur(0) duration by longer than the max dropdown value of 30s.

In my list I only have 0.5s, 0.9s, 5s+-, 20s+-, 30s+-, 2s, 1.5s, 0.6s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menu: BaseData -> Distributions -> Time